# What does large node mean?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am reading "Social and Economic Networks" by M.Jackson. It is about random graphs. On Chapter 4, it says

> [...] the degrees of two neighbors [i.e. neighboring nodes in a graph] are approximately independently distributed for large networks [i.e. graphs] provided the largest nodes are not too large.

What does "the largest nodes are not too large?"  In particular, what does a large node mean? Does it mean a node with a high number of neighbors?

Comment: The author is talking about degree sequences, thus a largest node is a node with largest degree in the network and the degree of a node is equal to the cardinality of its neighborhood.

In that sense the term "large" is to be understood relative to $n$, the number of nodes in the network (see page 117).